# BeautifulSoup returning incorrect text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the below site for live tennis scores. When the match is over the elements I'm scraping changes and I can get the score, but during the match when I search for the associated 'span' class where the score is kept I return the class but the score is blank (see below)

http://www.scoreboard.com/game/6LeqhPJd/#game-summary

```
score = score.findAll('span',attrs={'class':'scoreboard'})
```

output:

```
[<span class="scoreboard">-</span>, <span class="scoreboard">-</span>]
```

expected output

```
[<span class="scoreboard">1</span>, <span class="scoreboard">0</span>]
```

Using firebug I can see the score within these fields, however I can't seem to return it. Would anyone know why this would occur..?

NOTE: When the match in the above URL has finished the element for the score changes. This is only a problem for LIVE matches...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The webpage is using JavaScript. If you are downloading the URL with `urllib`, the JavaScript is not getting executed. So much of the HTML you are seeing in the browser is not getting generated.

One way to execute the JavaScript is to use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). 
Another way is to use [PyQt4](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro):

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtWebKit
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Render(QtWebKit.QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        QtWebKit.QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()
        self.app.quit()

url = 'http://www.scoreboard.com/game/6LeqhPJd/#game-summary'
r = Render(url)
content = unicode(r.frame.toHtml())
```

Once you have `content` (*after* the JavaScript has been executed) you can parse it with an HTML parser (like BeautifulSoup or lxml).

For example, using lxml:

```
import lxml.html as LH

def clean(text):
    return text.replace(u'\xa0', u'')

doc = LH.fromstring(content)   
result = []
for tr in doc.xpath('//tr[td[@class="left summary-horizontal"]]'):
    row = []
    for elt in tr.xpath('td'):
        row.append(clean(elt.text_content()))
    result.append(u', '.join(row[1:]))
print(u'\n'.join(result))
```

yields

```
Chardy J. (Fra), 2, 6, 77, , , , 
Zeballos H. (Arg), 0, 4, 63, , , ,
```

---

Using [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) and [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) (so that a GUI browser doesn't pop up), this is what the equivalent code would look like:

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import contextlib
import os
import lxml.html as LH

# define path to the phantomjs binary
phantomjs = os.path.expanduser('~/bin/phantomjs')
url = 'http://www.scoreboard.com/game/6LeqhPJd/#game-summary'
with contextlib.closing(webdriver.PhantomJS(phantomjs)) as driver:
    driver.get(url)
    content = driver.page_source
    doc = LH.fromstring(content)   
    result = []
    for tr in doc.xpath('//tr[td[@class="left summary-horizontal"]]'):
        row = []
        for elt in tr.xpath('td'):
            row.append(elt.text_content())
        result.append(u', '.join(row[1:]))
    print(u'\n'.join(result))
```

Both the Selenium/PhantomJS solution and the PyQt4 solution take about the same amount of time to run.

Comment: Thanks!, that works great! only question -: the conversion to javascript seems slow, if there a quicker way to do it..?

Comment: The two methods I'm somewhat familiar with are Selenium and PyQt4. Of the two, I think PyQt4 is quicker when it suffices. There are other ways, such as analyzing the JavaScript and seeing what requests ultimately provide the data you are after. That would probably run quicker.