# Python browser emulator with JS support

Tags: python, mechanize

I want to grab some data from a site. Usually I use `mechanize` for such things, but now the site gives the data with JS. Alas, `mechanize` doesn't support it.

What can I use instead?

Comment: Can you show some example data?

Comment: For example, this one:
http://apps.who.int/trialsearch/AdvSearch.aspx

There you can select ALL in `Recruitment status is` and Novartis on `Primary Sponsor`.

Then, when we submit it as a POST form, it gives us the data with JS paging.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are some options:

1. [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) ([tutorial](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html))

   - For headless automation, Selenium can be used in
     conjunction with [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)
2. [WebKit](http://www.webkit.org/)
3. [Spidermonkey](http://code.google.com/p/python-spidermonkey/)

Here are some code examples:

- [PyQt4 + WebKit](http://webscraping.com/blog/Scraping-JavaScript-webpages-with-webkit/)
- [An example using PyQt4+WebKit, and redone with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16386765/190597)