# How to scrape out of amazon.com

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the first offer from `'https://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox'` with Python (3.5) and BeautifulSoup4.

I thought this would refer it:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='a-section a-spacing-none tallCellView gridColumn4 singleCell', id='100_dealView_0'):
    print(div)
```

but obviously it isn't printing any reference/code... why?

The sourcecode:
[image]

Comment: Maybe this `div` is generated on the client side? Or is retrieved via AJAX? Or maybe its class or id is changing?

Comment: I can refer until 'GB-M-COMMON GB-SUPPLE' (first line of the sourcecode-image) any sub div-classes cant be referred.

Comment: Check the data in the soup: is the line you're searching for there? Are there any reason their lines missing? I'd guess they use AJAX to load this, but your Python code doesn't execute these AJAX requests (or any JavaScript at all), so the data isn't loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The product information is not coming directly into the html structure. It is inside a script that then is passed to the DOM executing some javascript.

I don't know right now how to use soup to get that information but, I would use something like:

```
$ pip install parsel

from parsel import Selector
import urllib.request
import re
import json

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox').read()
sel = Selector(unicode(a, 'utf-8'))
script = sel.xpath('//script[contains(., "dcsServerResponse")]').extract_first()
obj = re.search(r'dcsServerResponse   : ({.+}),\n    dealViewConfig', script, re.DOTALL).group(1)
json_response = json.loads(obj)

# now iterate the product deals
for k,v in json_response['dealDetails'].items():
    # do whatever you want with the information.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for the answers.

Some links which helped me and may help you (if you're having the same question).
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSH77vnOGqU

Eventually i ended up with a selenium-phantomJS headless browser.
[Python browser emulator with JS support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21777306/python-browser-emulator-with-js-support)

Cheers!