# Download a webpage using python 3 that contains script with data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this [website](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/financials?p=MSFT) in which I want to get the data of this webpage. so I tried this code in python 3.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urlopen("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/financials?p=MSFT").read()

f = open("D:/source.html", "wb")
f.write(html)
f.close()
```

the problem is that the downloaded page not contains all the data in the table if you checked the website the table has 2 parts of data which are Annual and Quarterly the Quarterly part does not show in the result.
I tried to use another library for this task and it downloads the full page with the data in the Quarterly and when i compared the 2 web pages the one i get from the library is a little bit have more size than the other one downloaded with the above code. 
want to do this in standard python 3.
also I don't know exactly what to search for on this part or what to call such kind of webpage so I need help to know why the webpage not downloaded completely? and how to solve it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the site that you want to access blocks crawling, so you should try to emulate a browser which the question below covers really well.
[Python browser emulator with JS support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21777306/python-browser-emulator-with-js-support)

Comment: i tired to use Python Selenium but the page never finishes load so I can't get the html even after i set a time to wait and then to get the result it download the normal HTML page without the full table. tell me if you want me to write the code i did, but it's the simple normal code example which loads the webpage using driver.get("URL") and then get page source code driver.page_source tell me if this wrong.

Comment: After going through the web-page it seems that the reason that Quarterly tab isn't coming in open is because it is created dynamically with ajax on a react back-end and using urlopen will download the current page which wont have the quarterly details .

As for how to proceed , try to fix your selenium page , if you can post your error or go with pyQT webkit